# GET followers/list using FABRIC ANDROID SDK?

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I need to get `followers list` of currently logged in user. I saw [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list) but how to make the URL request and manage the result. Can I make normal network request by using volley or something ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am also having same issue. Are you able to find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. Then I found java wrapper for this functionality **Twitter4j**. It is very easy to use. Following are the lines of code which I use for storing followers ids in a list.

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
twitter4j.Twitter twitter1;
ConfigurationBuilder config =
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .setOAuthConsumerKey(custkey)
                    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(custsecret)
                    .setOAuthAccessToken(accesstoken)
                    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accesssecret);

twitter1 = new TwitterFactory(config.build()).getInstance();



         while(cursor != 0 && length > 0) {
              System.out.println("in loop");
            try {
                IDs temp    = twitter1.friendsFollowers().getFollowersIDs(username, cursor);
                cursor      = temp.getNextCursor();
                tempids = temp.getIDs();
                length = temp.getIDs().length;
            } catch (twitter4j.TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (long id : tempids) {
                ids.add(id);
            }
        }`
```

I also asked the same question in Twitter community. You can check it out at
https://twittercommunity.com/t/get-followers-of-a-user-using-twitter-android-sdk/37740